# How to feed CMake with vcpkg information?

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg

Suppose I have installed some library with `vcpkg` and it's numerous dependencied (say `cgal`). Now I want to compile some program against these libraries with `CMake`.

How should I tell `CMake` about all locations of all libraries I have downloaded? Including main library I have installed? I have only one setting in `CMake`, called "source directory" which will point to my code. Where are settings for libraries?

---

```
D:\Users\ThirdPartyDesign\CGAL-5.0-examples\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2
λ env | grep CMAKE
CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\Users\ThirdPartyDesign\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake



D:\Users\ThirdPartyDesign\CGAL-5.0-examples\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2
λ cmake .
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindCGAL.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "CGAL", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "CGAL" with any of
  the following names:

    CGALConfig.cmake
    cgal-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "CGAL" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "CGAL_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "CGAL"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- This program requires the CGAL library, and will not be compiled.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/Users/ThirdPartyDesign/CGAL-5.0-examples/CGAL-5.0/examples/Triangulation_2
```

Answer (score 13):

Normally you need to set; `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` and `VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET`.

Set `VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET` to the vcpkg triplet that you are using. The default is `x86-windows`

Set `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` to point to `path_to_vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake`

Then you can use cmake functions such as `find_package` to find the required package.

see https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/examples/installing-and-using-packages.md#cmake-toolchain-file for more information.

Comment: What does "Set CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE" mean? Does it mean use set in the shell? Does it mean add a set line to the CMakeLists.txt? Does it mean use -DCMAKE... on the cmake command line?

Comment: @sigfpe Use it as -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=path_to_vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake
I'm not sure about other ways, but this one works
Make sure to do "vcpkg integrate install" first.

Answer (score 6):

I added the [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp.git) package through [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg.git). I used the following command to clone the vcpkg repository to the external folder, I even put it in an *install_dependencies.sh* file:

```
DIR="external"
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git "$DIR/vcpkg"
    cd "$DIR/vcpkg"
    ./bootstrap-vcpkg.sh
    ./vcpkg integrate install
    ./vcpkg install jsoncpp
```

Then, in the *CMakeLists.txt* file I added the following commands after the *add_executable* function:

```
# ...
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADERS})

#-- JSONCPP ------------------------------

set(JSON_INC_PATH external/vcpkg/packages/jsoncpp_x64-osx/include)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${JSON_INC_PATH})

set(JSON_LIB_PATH external/vcpkg/packages/jsoncpp_x64-osx/lib)
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${JSON_LIB_PATH})

#----------------------------------------

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
        #...
        jsoncpp
        )
```

Now after reloading, I can include the json library using:

```
#include <json/json.h>
# Rest of code here...
```