# How can I configure CMake with CGAL?

Tags: c++, cmake, cgal

I am working on the installation of CGAL for my 3D project.
I installed CGAL using the vcpkg package (library) and tried to configure a compiler/linker CMake with CGAL.

Unfortunately I am getting an error to configure CGAL with CMake (see below). How is it possible to link these two together? What does the error mean?

```
 ****CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:22 (find_package):
By not providing "FindCGAL.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "CGAL", but
CMake did not find one.
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "CGAL" with any of
the following names:
CGALConfig.cmake
cgal-config.cmake
Add the installation prefix of "CGAL" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"CGAL_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "CGAL"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.****
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Desktop/CGAL-5.0.2/examples/Triangulation_2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: Does the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59250626/how-to-feed-cmake-with-vcpkg-information) apply to your situation?

Comment: Also, Welcome! Can you provide your CMake code in your question post? Simply providing the error message does not provide a full picture of what is going on, and where the problem might be.