# How to link jsoncpp with cmake

Tags: c++, json, linux, cmake, jsoncpp

I cannot find a way to link jsoncpp with my executable. I have tried many things but none succeeded:

- linking jsoncpp_lib
- also what is written [here](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/issues/455#issuecomment-283921965):

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(JSONCPP jsoncpp)
link_libraries(${JSONCPP_LIBRARIES})
add_executable(myprogram myprogram.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myprogram ${JSONCPP_LIBRARIES})
```

I want to use the jsoncpp library that comes with ubuntu. Has anyone managed to do this?

```bash
$ ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjsoncpp.*

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjsoncpp.a   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjsoncpp.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjsoncpp.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjsoncpp.so.1.7.4
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8.0 FATAL_ERROR)

project(jsoncpp_example)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -Wall -Werror")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-lstdc++ -lpthread")

add_executable(parse main.cpp)
target_include_directories(parse PRIVATE include)
target_link_libraries(parse jsoncpp)
```

Parser.h

```cpp
#ifndef MY_PARSER_H
#define MY_PARSER_H

#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>

class MyParser {
public:
    MyParser() = default;
    ~MyParser() = default;
    
    inline static 
    Json::Value parse(const char* inputFile) {
        Json::Value val;
        std::ifstream ifs(inputFile);
        Json::Reader reader;
        reader.parse(ifs, val);
        return val;
    }

};

#endif /* MY_PARSER_H */
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Parser.h"

int main(){
    Json::Value val = MyParser::parse("input.json");
    std::cout << val["name"] << std::endl;
}
```

Ubuntu 18.04, compiling with clan-8.0

```bash
CXX=clang-8 cmake ..
make -j
```

The error I get

```
Scanning dependencies of target parse
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/parse.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable parse
CMakeFiles/parse.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `Json::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Json::Value const&)'
CMakeFiles/parse.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `MyParser::parse(char const*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN8MyParser5parseEPKc[_ZN8MyParser5parseEPKc]+0x349): undefined reference to `Json::Reader::parse(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Json::Value&, bool)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
CMakeFiles/parse.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'parse' failed
make[2]: *** [parse] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/parse.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/parse.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wiki mentions

```
get_target_property(JSON_INC_PATH jsoncpp_lib INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
include_directories(${JSON_INC_PATH})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} jsoncpp_lib)
```

but I couldn't get that to work myself. If you have the `jsoncpp` `.cmake` files installed in a place searched automatically, this could be an option:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8.0 FATAL_ERROR)

project(jsoncpp_example)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(JSONCPP jsoncpp)

set(CMAKE_THREAD_PREFER_PTHREAD TRUE) # these are to use the prefered -pthread flag
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG TRUE) # over the -lpthread option
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

add_executable(parse main.cpp)
set_property(TARGET parse PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
target_compile_options(parse PRIVATE -Wall -Werror)

target_link_libraries(parse PRIVATE Threads::Threads ${JSONCPP_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: This gives me `/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/parse.dir/main.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZSt9terminatev@@GLIBCXX_3.4'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line`  I guess I still need `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-lstdc++")`?

Comment: With the liker flag it worked, thank you!

Comment: @afvmil You're welcome. It seems the OS X delvelopment toolchain is setup in a slightly differnet way than I'm used to. I found this explanation why: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655588?answerId=665804022#665804022

Comment: I stayed away from `pkg`

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I didn’t use `pkg`. It was another ton of work. It frustrated me and I wasn’t too happy about that.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon I still do not understand what your comment is about. If you have another answer to the question, please post it separately.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I’m sorry I did. There is nothing wrong with your answer. It just didn’t solve my problem instead it put me through hell. I guess I wasn’t thinking straight and I was just frustrated. I’m trying to undo my mistake but SO doesn’t allow me to.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon _"It just didn’t solve my problem instead it put me through hell."_ - I see. You can always ask a separate question or ask for clarification under an existing answer.  Regarding undoing your mistake: You can't unless I edit the answer :-) I would be willinng to clarify the answer if I just knew why it didn't work for you.

Comment: Installing `pkg` was a disaster. It  threw errors here and there.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon Yes I got that you had troubles with it but I can't update the answer if I don't get the details. If you are still interested in finding a solution to it, perhaps asking a question where you show all the details would be best?

Answer (score 2):

With cmake 3.22 i got it to work:

```
find_package(jsoncpp REQUIRED)
...
target_link_libraries({app_name} ... jsoncpp_lib)
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who came to this topic, like me, who are looking for a way to include the jsoncpp library in a C++ project with cmake. I solved this problem by cloning the [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg.git) repository into an *external* folder and installing the jsoncpp package through vcpkg, as the official [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp.git) repository suggests. I've better described the solution to this problem [in this topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667812/12460626) since it was more generic in search terms.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux this worked for me

1. install the dev libs.

   sudo apt-get install libjsoncpp-dev
2. in cmakelists.

pkg_search_module(JSONCPP jsoncpp)

add to...

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${JSONCPP_LIBRARIES})

3. cmake .
4. make