# vcpkg: classic vs manifest mode

Tags: cmake, vcpkg

I am trying to understand how to use the [`classic` mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/consume/classic-mode?tabs=msbuild%2Cbuild-MSBuild) of vcpkg (Visual Studio BuildTools 2022 + standalone installation).

I've used DCMTK as reference cmake project. Since it does not contains a vcpkg.json I added one:

```
> cat .\vcpkg.json
{
  "name": "dcmtk",
  "dependencies": [
    {
      "name": "libpng"
    }
  ]
}
```

Followed by:

```
  variables:
    VCPKG_DEFAULT_TRIPLET: x64-windows-static
  script:
    - cmake -S . -B build1
      -GNinja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
      -DDCMTK_USE_FIND_PACKAGE_WIN_DEFAULT=TRUE
      -DVCPKG_MANIFEST_MODE=ON
      -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
```

I can see in my gitlab output:

```
-- Info: DCMTK PNG support will be enabled
```

Now I change into:

```
  variables:
    VCPKG_DEFAULT_TRIPLET: x64-windows-static
  script:
    - rm vcpkg.json
    - vcpkg install libpng
    - cmake -S . -B build2
      -GNinja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
      -DDCMTK_USE_FIND_PACKAGE_WIN_DEFAULT=TRUE
      -DVCPKG_MANIFEST_MODE=OFF
      -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
```

I now see:

```
-- Warning: PNG support will be disabled because libpng was not found.
```

What did I misunderstood from the `classic` mode documentation ? What step am I missing so that it behave as the `manifest` mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is rather [evasive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/buildsystems/cmake-integration#vcpkg_target_triplet):

> **VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET** This setting controls the triplet vcpkg will install and consume libraries from.
>
> If unset, vcpkg will automatically detect an appropriate default
> triplet given the current compiler settings. If you change this CMake
> variable, you must delete your cache and reconfigure.

It does not describe case where it fails to detect an appropriate default...which seems to be my case here.

Solution is simply:

```
  variables:
    VCPKG_DEFAULT_TRIPLET: x64-windows-static
  script:
    - rm vcpkg.json
    - vcpkg install libpng
    - cmake -S . -B build2
      -GNinja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
      -DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-windows-static ### Important ###
      -DDCMTK_USE_FIND_PACKAGE_WIN_DEFAULT=TRUE
      -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
```

For reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59251091/136285

---

I was able to diagnose the failure to find png using the debug mode of cmake `cmake --debug-find`:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE.html

Excerpt:

```
CMake Debug Log at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake:122 (find_path):
  find_path called with the following settings:

    VAR: ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR
    NAMES: "zlib.h"
    Documentation: Path to a file.
    Framework
      Only Search Frameworks: 0
      Search Frameworks Last: 1
      Search Frameworks First: 0
    AppBundle
      Only Search AppBundle: 0
      Search AppBundle Last: 1
      Search AppBundle First: 0
    CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_PATH: 1
    CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH: 1
    CMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH: 1
    CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH: 1
    CMAKE_FIND_USE_INSTALL_PREFIX: 1

  find_path considered the following locations:

    C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include/include/zlib.h
    C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include/zlib.h
    C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include/zlib.h
    [...]
```

Answer (score 2):

In `manifest mode`, dependencies are managed automatically by vcpkg based on the `vcpkg.json` manifest file present in your project directory. When you invoke CMake, it uses this file to resolve and install dependencies before the build starts.

In `classic mode`, dependencies must be installed manually using the `vcpkg install` command before you invoke CMake. The installed packages are then found by CMake based on the configuration provided by vcpkg's toolchain file.<>

---

In your first scenario (manifest mode), you had a `vcpkg.json` in your project, and you enabled manifest mode with `-DVCPKG_MANIFEST_MODE=ON`. That allowed vcpkg to automatically manage `libpng` for you.

In your second scenario (classic mode), you removed the `vcpkg.json` and used `vcpkg install libpng` to manually install the package. However, you also used `-DVCPKG_MANIFEST_MODE=OFF` which is unnecessary because classic mode is the default behavior when no `vcpkg.json` is found.

---

To make sure `libpng` is found in classic mode, make sure that:

1. the `vcpkg install` command successfully installs `libpng` and any of its dependencies.
2. the `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` is correctly set to the `vcpkg.cmake` script. That is done in your command, but make sure the path is correct and accessible.
3. the `VCPKG_DEFAULT_TRIPLET` is correctly set to match your build environment (`x64-windows-static` in your case). That makes sure CMake looks for the libraries in the correct vcpkg packages directory.

If after these steps `libpng` is still not found, it could be due to:

- Caching issues: [CMake caches variables and paths](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/CMake%20Cache.html). Try clearing your CMake cache or specifying a different build directory after changing modes.
- Path misconfiguration: Make sure the path specified in [`CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Cross%20Compiling%20With%20CMake.html?highlight=dcmake_toolchain_file#toolchain-files) correctly points to the `vcpkg.cmake` file.

Example for classic Mode:

```
  variables:
    VCPKG_DEFAULT_TRIPLET: x64-windows-static
  script:
    - vcpkg install libpng
    - cmake -S . -B build2
      -GNinja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
      -DDCMTK_USE_FIND_PACKAGE_WIN_DEFAULT=TRUE
      -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
```

Double-check `vcpkg install` is executed in the same environment where your CMake build will run so that it uses the same triplet and paths are correctly resolved.

Comment: Could you post the relevant portion of your `build2/CMakeCache.txt` ?